# Nuget Parameterized Content Path

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'd like to see Nuget have a parameter-substitution capability with content paths, allowing me to do something like this:

```
\content\someFile\$somePlace$\myCode.cs
```

In theory, I would use an `install.psl` script to set the value of `$somePlace$` before it is copied.  Is there a way to do this?

If not, and I presume not, then what is my next option?  Would it make sense for me to move  `myCode.cs` into the `\tools` folder, and then have `install.ps1` simply copy it to a dynamic path as needed?  Is there a better "standard" way to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can leave myCode.cs in the folder it resides but I'm affraid install.ps1 should be doing the copy work. Also make sure that uninstall.ps1 inverts the operation and removes the file again (if not changed).

Comment: The "files" package element, assuming it supports `replacement tokens`, is almost what I want...but not quite.